# AnkhSVN for VS2010: How can I view history for "parent" files like aspx that have codebehind and designing beneath it?

Tags: history, ankhsvn

I am using AnkhSVN with VS2010 and am trying to view history on an .aspx file so that I can view differences between an old version and my working copy.  When I right-click on the file, I see View History, but when the History Viewer opens, I don't have the same context menu options, especially Show Changes which is the one I need.  I am able to do what I want with the codebehind and designer without any problems.  What I think is confusing Ankh is that the aspx file is actually a parent file to the designer and codebehind.  I comes to this conclusion because, when I look at history for the aspx, I see all three files listed in the History Viewer window title, whereas I only see a single file name when I view history for the designer and codebehind.

Is this a known issue that has a work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this:

- Open the file in your editor
- Right Click -> Subversion -> View History.

We are working on a way to make this easier from the history viewer itself.
(You can also doubleclick on the changed files in the log viewer to see the changes in just that revision)

Comment: Just went with your double-clicking of the items in the Changed Path pane and it worked.  I like the TFS or SourceGear user-friendliness and untuitiveness much more, but I guess you get what you pay for.  Thanks.